# Good way to deploy a database in a Perl module?

Tags: database, perl

Does anyone have recommendations for deploying a database as part of a Perl application which is itself deployed as a Perl module?

Generally, I include a schema in a SQL file, but I would like to have a more automated process.

Comment: This may help:  [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/DBD-SQLite-0.31/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm)

Comment: Yes SQLite is fine if I want to deploy the entire database and I don't mind any of the limitations of it.  But the question still stands if I want to use something like PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: doubtful that you could do this with something heavier like Postgres or MySQL, but I'd be interested in seeing if anyone's done something similar.

Comment: Upgradable schema as Perl classes: http://p3rl.org/DBIx::Class::Schema::Versioned

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/release/DBIx-Class) ORM has support for [versioning and deploying](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aCookbook#Schema-versioning) database schemas. You can have your users either update manually or you can provide scripts. This is what I usually do, since it also allows me to deploy a SQLite database file to use during development while staging/production can be any other supported system.

There is also [DBIx::Class::DeploymentHandler](https://metacpan.org/release/DBIx-Class-DeploymentHandler), which I haven't used that much yet, so can't fully comment. It seems to have very [good documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aDeploymentHandler%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro) though, so it's also worth a look.

Comment: I like the look of DeploymentHandler.

Comment: Yea, me too. It came after I started doing deployments with pure DBIC and I didn't have time yet to fully work myself into DBIC:DH. Have to get to that one of these weekends.